# GoogleMap api v2 is not sharpening on zooming

Tags: android, google-maps, android-maps-v2

So yea i impleted googlemap v2 to my android project.

When i zooming, the map sharpening for some range, then it stops and never sharps again.
Is it a known issue?
I cant see roads, streets, even cities.

And an other similiar thing: 
The map is only visible in a rectangle, and i cant do any moves, zooms, or anything else to get the map render the blank areas.

This map is like a handicapped map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. Connect to Wifi so you make sure you have a stable connection. Then run your app and see if it loads. It seems that your map is not able to download the map headers, try it and let me know.

Comment: Accepted answer is like "letting you know"